# You draw 5 cards out of deck of N cards, needed to calculate probabilty of picking 2 marked cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

So, there is a deck of N cards ($N-2$ are blank, and $2$ are marked), you draw $5$ cards with each attempt, what is probability of picking 2 marked cards with the first and each new try? (The deck will be reshuffled, if there are not enough cards to draw.)

I tried to solve the problem using $_{N-5(x-1)}C_5$ ($x$ is number of attempts), but I don't understand how to subtract amount of right combinations from wrongs ones in this case.

Comment: After each try, are the cards you picked shuffled back into the deck or set aside?

Comment: @eyeballfrog It is not stated, but I would read this as 5 cards drawn without replacement, and then all 5 put back for the next try

Comment: @N.F.Taussig if I attempt to pick 2 cards, the probability of picking one marked card on the first try is $\frac{2}{N}$, and the probability of picking one on the second try is $\frac{1}{N-1}$. When I add up these probabilities, I get $\frac{2}{N(N-1)}$. However, I'm unsure if I can use this method to solve my problem.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I added that the deck will be reshuffled, only if there are not enough cards to draw.

Comment: The probability of selecting the two marked cards from $N$ cards when two cards are drawn is indeed $\frac{2}{N} \cdot \frac{1}{N - 1}$, which can be expressed in the form $\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{N}{2}}$.  If you select $2$ marked cards when five cards are drawn from the deck, how many unmarked cards must you select?  I meant to write that $\binom{n}{k}$ can be produced by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig from these $5$ drawn cards I must select $3$ unmarked ones.

Comment: That is correct.  Therefore, the number of favorable cases for the first attempt is $\binom{2}{2}\binom{N - 3}{3}$ since you must select both of the marked cards and three of the $N - 3$ unmarked cards.

Comment: So I can simplify $\binom{2}{2},\binom{N-3}{3}$ to $1 * \binom{N-3}{3}$ and divide by $\binom{N}{5}$ to get a probability of picking both cards on the first try? Also, if the marked cards were different, would $\binom{2}{2}$ become $\binom{2}{1}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Why $(N-3)$ unmarked cards ? Did you mean $(N-2)$?

Comment: @trueblueanil  I did mean $N - 2$.

Comment: @JonMadden  I was careless in my last comment.  As true blue anil pointed out, I meant $\binom{2}{2}\binom{N - 2}{3}$ in my previous comment, so the probability of selecting both of the two marked cards in the first try would be $\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{N - 2}{3}}{\binom{N}{5}}$.  This is true regardless of whether or not the marked cards are distinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzqWa.jpg)

I think you have to put back in the deck every time you draw 5 cards, otherwise the situation is too complicated, as I wrote in the picture.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your answer using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) since images cannot be searched and may not be readable by users who rely on screen readers.

Comment: $k=3$ in $\binom{N-2}{3}$, as it is an amount of possible combinations of the 3 rest cards?